# Can the Lumia 535 be upgraded to support 4G networks?

Tags: lumia, windows-mobile

I saw [one news](http://www.themobileindian.com/news/15977_Microsoft-reveals-Lumia-640-Lumia-640-XL-in-3G/4G-variants) about the Lumia 640, which can be upgraded to 4G.

Does the Lumia 535 also support 4G?
Would you please share the mobile list of smartphone that can be upgraded to 4G?

Because I plan to purchase a 4G mobile phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are separate hardware variants, so a 3G handset cannot be upgraded to 4G, but a 4G handset would obviously also work when only 3G signal was available.

Comment: i accept your statement. but Microsoft dealer said to me, by default lumia 535 hardware support 4G but needs to update software.then they told dont by 4g mobile in feature microsoft give software update for lumia 535 like lumia 640XL

Comment: Worth remembering that is a salesperson's advice which may be motivated by other factors (such as shifting lower spec stock). If there was only one model, I would expect there to be two prices, and have it described as two variants. I would also be surprised if it were only disabled in the firmware, as there would be the cost of additional/more advanced components to support 4G over 3G for devices where it was never intended to be used.

Comment: Of course, if a customer were to buy a 3G variant because a salesperson claimed you could upgrade, and then the customer found they couldn't, the customer's only option would to buy **another** device, which may end up coming from that same salesperson, who is the only winner in that scenario...

Answer (score -1):

I guess No. Microsoft did a firmware update to support 4G in India and other countries, and some of the Lumia devices does come with 4G support and need this firmware update in order to start functioning. However, this firmware upgrade was limited to Lumia 1520, Lumia 1320, Lumia 1020, Lumia 920, Lumia 925, Lumia 830 and Lumia 625.

Comment: @rowland shad, i am not accept your statement. may after window 10 update they provide the 4g service for 535

Comment: well, I didn't list Lumia 535.. But, I am using 4g in my Lumia 625.